# Kubuntu 13.04 fails to boot after software update

Tags: boot, kubuntu, software-updater

This morning Kubuntu presented, as usual, a list of automatic software update. It was an important list, with a lot of applications involved and KDE. There has been an error with some of the packages but the update manager told to restart the systems, but the system is unable to boot. Trying to restart with older kernels or safe mode, also fail. Tried the option "fix packages" but again there are problemas with some KDE packages.

GRUB is working, even kubuntu logo is displayed but I never reach to login sreen, some error messages very quickly are displayed (I don't have time to read them) and then a black screen is displayed. However shutdown works and even shutdown text messages are displayed.

At this moment I can't use my computer.

Thank you.

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Can You login to a cli shell with `Ctrl-Alt-F2`? You can try to downgrade a kernel from there: `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-23-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic` to switch to 3.5.0-23 kernel. Looks to me as if either You don't have a video driver which works with an updated kernel, or Xorg configs got messed up. It might be faster to boot from live cd, copy data and configs (dot file), and installing clean Kubuntu (I would lock the kernel version if I were You).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk was full. Cleaned, and fixed broken packages from advanced boot.